# Package already installed but getting error like No module name "plspm" in Python?

Tags: python

I have started getting this error for a "plspm" module in python which is part of R library after I 'conda install plspm' on my windows 10 OS. Installation has been done properly but i could not able to import plspm in python getting "No module" error. Please anyone help me to resolve.Thanks.

version of r-plspm is -0.4.9
needed packages already installed(scipy,skit-learn,pandas,numpy,statsmodule).

command used to install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-plspm
```

Screen shot of installed plspm:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: try this : `python3 -m pip install --user plspm`

Comment: What is the output of this command `which python`? Probably isn't the one with anaconda

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar this cpmmand is for normal python pip environment but i'm using "conda" environment.

Comment: @Anwarvic its anaconda only.. command i have mentioned above to install plspm.

Comment: @Sruthipriyanga what is the output of this command `which python`??

Comment: @Anwarvic python version is 3.6.8

Comment: @Sruthipriyanga no, that's not the output... the output should be the path of the python executable which I assume it won't be the one under anaconda